# R - ave rollapply error: k <= n is not TRUE

Tags: r, rollapply

I am trying to calculate a rolling mean of value grouped by multiple dimensions in R. Something I would do in SQL in the following way:

```
AVG(value) OVER 
   (PARTITION BY dim1, dim2 ORDER BY date 
       RANGE BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

The following seems to work if I select just a few dimensions:

```
s <- ave(df$value, 
     list(df$dim1, df$dim2), 
     FUN= function(x) rollapply(x, 5, mean, align='right'))
```

but gives the following error when I select full set of dimensions:

```
Error: k <= n is not TRUE
```

I get the same error when I run:

```
rollapply(c(1:2), 3, mean, align='right')
```

so I guess the issue is that some combinations of dimensions do not have enough values to calculate mean.

How could I overcome it? I am fine with having a NA as a result for those combinations. Any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: Well, in your last example, you are trying to use the *last three values* on each iteration...but the iteration vector `c(1:2)` only has two!

Comment: Yes, I am aware what the issue is, second example is just to illustrate it. The question is, how can I overcome it and get NA if there are to few elements to calculate rollapply instead of getting an error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`roll_meanr` from the `RcppRoll` package will do this by default:

```
library(RcppRoll)
> roll_meanr(c(1:2), 3)
# [1] NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

`rollapply(c(1:10), 3, mean, align='right', fill=NA)` should do the trick, provided your vector is long enough to produce any data.

note that `rollapply(c(1:2), 3, mean, align='right', fill=NA)` still returns the error for the reason stated by @robert-krzyzanowski